# Global integers being assigned the wrong value

Tags: android, android-view

I use my custom View, `ColorStrip`, in two places in my application: in `ListView` items and in a separate `FragmentActivity`. The ListView items display my View correctly, but for some odd reason when a `ColorStrip` is created for my `FragmentActivity`, the `hPx` and `wPx` variables are set to, of all numbers, 102 and 8, respectively. If I check the values of these variables when they are being created for the ListView items (during the execution of `onCreate()`, they both show up as zero. But when it goes to create a ColorStrip for my FragmentActivity, they are assigned those weird values.

I don't understand why the variables are getting assigned values other than 0 when it creates it for the FragmentActivity.

Here is all the code for my subclass of `View`:

```
public class ColorStrip extends View {

public ShapeDrawable mDrawable;
private static int hPx = 0;
private static int wPx = 0;

public ColorStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());

    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.ColorStrip, 0, 0);
    try {
        int color = a.getInt(R.styleable.ColorStrip_color, 0);
        if (color != 0)
            setColor(color);
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }

}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (wPx == 0)
        wPx = getWidth();
    if (hPx == 0)
        hPx = getHeight();
    mDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, wPx, hPx);
    mDrawable.draw(canvas);
}

public void setColor(int color) {
    mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(color);
}
}
```

Here's the XML for the ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<com.acedit.assignamo.ui.ColorStrip
    android:id="@+id/assignment_list_color_strip"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/color_strip_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and the XML for the FragmentActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ColorStrip="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.acedit.assignamo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.acedit.assignamo.ui.ColorStrip
        android:id="@+id/assignment_view_color_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/assignment_view_color_strip_height" />
```

Why are the variables being assigned these weird values?

Comment: @auselen Aha! Duh. (facepalm) Write it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm wondering why I even declared them as static in the first place... Must have been for efficiency reasons...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't declare hPx and wPx as static. Also it is not a really good idea to cache them and just set with the first call into onDraw. A better place is [View.onSizeChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) according to [Custom Drawing](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html#layouteevent) document at http://android.developer.com.

Comment: How do you suggest I set my width and height?

Comment: View.onSizeChanged http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html#layouteevent

Comment: Thanks! Now my View is totally reusable.